# Consumer stopped after authorizationException and never recover

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-integration-dsl

I am using Spring Integration with spring-Kafka so I have created custom listener's to read messages from topics and put them on the spring integration channel.
After certain interval say like 10-12 hours pod restarts and Application start's successfully with no error but after sometime.

**Note:- This kafka_outgoing_topic does not belongs to my microservice and is not present in my code anywhere.**

I see below error in logs:-

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [kafka_outgoing_topic]
"
"2022-08-13T09:24:12.617+0000","2022-08-13 09:24:01.975","1 --- [customlistner-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Authorization Exception and no authorizationExceptionRetryInterval set

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [kafka_outgoing_topic]
"

 [customlistner-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : group-id : Consumer stopped.
```

After this point of time my custom listener never starts.

Below is my code:-

```
@Bean("ConsumerBean")
    public KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<String, String> kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter() {
        KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<String, String> kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter = new KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<>(listener());
        kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.setOutputChannel(messageFromKafka());
        kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.setAutoStartup(true);
        return kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter;
    }
@Bean("customlistner")
    public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> listener()  {
        ContainerProperties properties = new ContainerProperties(kafkaTopic);
        properties.setGroupId("group-id");
        return (ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>) new ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<>(consumerFactory, properties);
         
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to follow that `Authorization Exception and no authorizationExceptionRetryInterval set` error recommendation.

See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#kafka-container

> As of version 2.8, a new container property `authExceptionRetryInterval` has been introduced. This causes the container to retry fetching messages after getting any `AuthenticationException` or `AuthorizationException` from the `KafkaConsumer`. This can happen when, for example, the configured user is denied access to read a certain topic or credentials are incorrect. Defining `authExceptionRetryInterval` allows the container to recover when proper permissions are granted.

Sounds like not only your pod is restarted, but some other which is responsible for Apache Kafka broker and you have to wait sometime until it recreates all the topics you are interested in.

Comment: In this case if I want to add Event on customListner is stopped and running  how can I do that. I have gone through document and found that @kafkalistner can only be found in KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.

Comment: Not sure what event you mean, but that is correct: to restart the listener manually you have to ask that registry.

Comment: I want to add events programmatically if my consumer goes down. So how can I add my custom consumer to KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry

Comment: What events, please? Why do you worry about `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry`? Looks like you deal with Spring Integration: see its dynamic `IntegrationFlow` support: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-runtime-flows. You just can add a flow with a fresh `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`. This one is not tied to `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry`

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by setting the authExceptionRetryInterval

```
consumerFactory.setContainerCustomizer(container -> container.getContainerProperties().setAuthorizationExceptionRetryInterval(Duration.ofMinutes(10L)));
```

Based on the spring kafka doc.

> By default, no interval is configured - authentication and
> authorization errors are considered fatal, which causes the container
> to stop.